# One function produces two different results? callback hell

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

```
TABS.cutoffs = {};
TABS.cutoffs.initialize = function(callback) {
  var self = this;

  $("select[name=selectlanguage]").on("change", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("languageValue", $(this).val());
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('languageValue'), "inside$JqueryFunction");
  });

  console.log(localStorage.getItem('languageValue'), "outsidetheFunction");

  if (callback) callback();

};
```

In HTML:

```
<td>
  <select class="dropdown" id="selectlanguage" name="selectlanguage">
    <option id="enBtn" value="en">English</option>
    <option id="zhBtn" value="zh">简体中文</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

In console it said:

```
en outsidetheFunction
zh inside$JqueryFunction
```

See? it should be the same, like either:

```
en outsidetheFunction
en inside$JqueryFunction
```

or

```
zh outsidetheFunction
zh inside$JqueryFunction
```

Why does `localStorage.getItem('languageValue')` become different inside and outside of the function `$("select[name=selectlanguage]").on("change", function()` ?

Comment: Because it *changes* after you logged it outside of the event handler?

Comment: `var a = 1; console.log(a); a = 2; // Why does the console say a is 1?`

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback hell here.

Here's what happens when the `initialize` function is called :

- the change event handler is set (but it's not called)
- the localStorage is read and printed in the console

Some other time - I guess, later - if you change the selected option in your select, the new selected value will be written in the local storage.

So, the scenario you're getting is very normal :

First, `"en outsidetheFunction"` is printed in the console. Most probably because somehow, "en" was written in localStorage. From a previous execution, I suppose.

Then, `"zh inside$JqueryFunction"` is printed in the console.
Most probably because you selected "zh" in your select and it triggered the change event, which wrote in localStorage and printed the new value.